# Extending compose UI - Missing Tokens

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I try to extend the compose UI to add attachments from an outside server, I try first to use the `newUpdateDraftActionResponseBuilder()` function but it's just to add content to the draft body.
So now, I try to get the draft itself in the way to make a simple `draft.update()` but when I try to get the info of the last draft, I have this error:

> "Missing access token for authorization. Request:
>   MailboxService.GetMessage".

Here is my code, and the error is on the second line:

```
var draft = GmailApp.getDrafts()[0];
var attachmentList = draft.getMessage().getAttachments();
```

Have you an idea to get this token?

Comment: Have you included from your `manifest.json` file the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose` scope? This is for managing drafts and for sending emails. You can also check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47225189/cant-access-gmail-drafts-via-gmail-add-ons) for this related issue.

Comment: Hi, yes I have, I have added all the necessary scope, this is why I don't know what is the problem...

Comment: "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://mail.google.com/",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.action",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale"
  ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution, this error seems to come from a conflict between several scopes. After removing unnecessary scopes, it is working!

```
"oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://mail.google.com/",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale"
  ]
```